# How to reset product id?

Tags: product, ce-1.7.0.2, product-list

I am using Magento CE 1.7.0.2. My Store product catalog have 1245 products with last `product id` 1245.

Yesterday I uploaded new 5 products using Magmi which create new products with `product ids`  1246 to 1250. All these products were disabled so no order placed for these new products.  Now due to some reason I need to delete these 5 products and upload (using Magmi) new 5 products.

How I can reset `product id` so new product ids start again from `1246`?

Answer (score 1):

Hy, you can do it directly from the mysql or phpAdmin,

```
ALTER TABLE catalog_product_entity AUTO_INCREMENT = 1246;
```

please check che spellingo of the table name and look for any db_prefix you may use